# CUDA - how to convert exp( 1i * x )?

Tags: cuda

I want to calculate some exp() like this.

`float t = 5.0;
cuComplex res = expf(1i*t);`

but, can't execute functions. that I think cuda compiler is not supporting like complex argument expf() function.

find some examples describes exp(x + iy)..
I want exp(x*i)....

Comment: Euler's formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula

Comment: self solved.. thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved myself...

```
__device__ __forceinline__ cuComplex _exp (cuComplex z)
{
    cuComplex res;
    float t = expf(z.x);
    sincosf(z.y, &res.y, &res.x);
    res.x *= t;
    res.y *= t;
    return res;
}
```

partial source

```
    /* 1i*t = 0+ti  |  -1i*t = 0-ti */
    cuComplex _gbp, _gfp;
    _gbp.x = 0;
    _gbp.y = t;
    _gfp.x = 0;
    _gfp.y = -t;

    cuComplex res_b = _exp(_gbp);
    cuComplex res_f = _exp(_gfp);
```

Comment: See also [this answer](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/505308/cuda-programming-and-performance/complex-number-exponential-function/post/3603793/#3603793) at NVIDIA forums.

Comment: yeah. it's almost same